# Replacing a Cast Iron Sink with a Stainless sink

Tags: kitchens, sink

We have granite counter tops and are replacing a cast iron sink with a stainless one. We bought a 33x22" sink (which is the size of the Cast iron) and because of the clips (which the cast iron doesn't use) it wont fit in the hole. We bought (online) a 31.5x20.5" sink which is the measurement of the hole but don't know if that will work either because the clips may not reach. We really need some help here.

A. What is the right size sink, and B. What do we do to get the right sink to fit? We are new at this so I don't know if I've done something wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did the original sink have a rim on top integral with the sink? Or was the rim a separate metal piece and the cast iron sink attached to that? The prior sink was porcelain on cast iron, right?

Comment: I'm sorry. While its the same size as the cast iron, to install you have to use clips, which the hole seems to have been cut just to accommodate a 33x22 cast iron which doesn't need the extra room for clips.

Comment: The original sink is one piece.

Comment: And why haven't you checked whether the second replacement sink will work yet?

Comment: Are you trying to do undermount or above mount?

Comment: The second one wont be here till tomorrow. I just didnt know if it will work because its the exact same size as the hole and the clips may not reach.

Comment: Its going to be over mount as well

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00MEYX46C/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1  Here is a link to the replacement sink

Comment: An over mounted sink will not need clips. RTV silicone (maybe even plumber's putty?) and gravity will hold it in place. Our soapstone countertop is cut on the underside for clips and has clips holding the under-mounted sink, but I think the weight is mostly held by the sealant, which I think is RTV silicone.

Comment: How would I secure the sink with out the clips?

Comment: The Sink doesn't weigh very much.

Comment: Proper silicone caulk (would not suggest plumbers putty as it doesn't act like a glue) all around the "lip" of the sink where it meets the granite.  Once the silicon cures it'll bond to the granite and the sink and hold the sink in place.

Comment: As for "will it fit or not" - you maybe should make sure you understand the dimensions of what you buy before you buy.  We can't tell you the sink dimensions vs. the lip dimensions.  The product can.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. For some reason I thought it would flex. SO should we use the Sink we bought that is the exact same size as the hole? Or should we remove the clip holders on the first sink?

Comment: If the clip bracket is spot welded to the sink, do not try to remove it. This sink may yet be returned for credit and to save a valuable item.  Wait until your new sink arrives and see if it fits as is. If the new one fits and has clamp rails, then maybe use them or maybe not

Comment: I agree on that. I'm not going to mess with the brackets. Though the question is whats the next step if the new sink doesn't fit? Because its dimensions are the EXACT same as sink hole.

Comment: You might have to have a granite counter company enlarge the hole for the sink. This may be easy for them, call and ask. There may be a limit as to what they can do in place (as opposed to in their workshop) and maybe the width on front and back must be above a certain limit to resist cracking.  I have to believe that  you can get a sink that will fit the opening as it is. Let me get this straight: the first sink has "rails" for clips and these interfere with it's fitting? On the front and back only, or on the sides too? Usually the installation instructions give the size of the opening req'd.

Comment: I'd be cutting the rails off the first sink and using silicone caulk to mount it. It's still not clear what the problem was, though. A sink the same size as the opening won't work.

Comment: @isherwood, how would you cut off the rails (which might be just short brackets)? He might not have an angle grinder and the skill to do this. He could take the sink to a kitchen install shop and have them do it.

Comment: Call a granite counter top company and have them install the first sink if that is your design preference. They could notch the granite counter top and allow it to fit. You will be looking at that sink for a long time; get what you want.

Comment: Notching is then out of the question they'd have to enlarge the opening. Even if you cut off the brackets the sink itself might interfere. What do the installation instructions say about size of opening required?

Answer (score 0):

Cut the countertop. If the reason it doesn't fit is because the clip bracket interferes then you shouldn't need to cut much. The countertop appears to be granite or some other solid surface so you would have to hire someone to cut it for you.

Comment: There are almost certainly better options to be had than an expensive and messy stone cut.

Comment: "Get the right size sink" would be a better answer.

Comment: I appreciate wanting to get the right size sink but I've look everywhere and I cant find one that fits that hole. at least a stainless steel.

Comment: Evidently that opening was cut for the specific cast iron sink originally installed. Read the instructions for the first SS sink and the SS one that is coming. If the specs don't match the opening, don't try to force it.